# Ideal Way to control shot extraction with Gaggia Classic

Tags: brewing-process, espresso, temperature, extraction, tamping

Wanted to know if anyone has a really good, possibly verified method of controlling shot preparation and extraction with an unmodified Gaggia Classic espresso machine.  I don't have, nor do I want to add a PID.

So, what is your method?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to control of shot extraction without adding excessively complicated electronics (if by PID you mean proportional-integral-derivative controller) is:

- How fine is the bean grounding (the finer the grounding, the higher the density -> the slower the extraction).
- Applied pressure on the grounded beans in the machine group head (the higher the pressure applied (similarly) -> the slower the extraction).
- pressure and temperature are also important parameters to be concerned before moving to PID control (for example your extraction time/lenght could be longer but if the temperature of the water is low, there won't be excessive essential oil extraction).